# How would I auto Populate a Input Text Box VALUE to be the same as the NAME?

Tags: javascript, css, forms

I am working for a client who needs their forms to show a value inside of their text box on a form, however with their system they are unable to do this due to how the module is coded.

What would be the best way to do this as I am unable to edit the source code of the form creation module to allow for a value to be set automatically when a user creates the form.

I know there are ways with JavaScript that this could be done, but most I have found require editing the input boxes or placing styles / attributes on the form itself which I do not have access to.

I do however have pre-existing styles on these areas of code along with a wrapper around the form itself that could target specific areas inside it with styling or script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML example:**

```
<form name="foobar">
    <input name="my_name_1"/>
    <input name="my_name_2"/>
    <input name="my_name_3"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function putNamesAsValues(formname){
    var elements = document.forms[formname].elements;
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
        if( elements[i].tagName.toLowerCase().indexOf('input') != -1 )
            elements[i].value = elements[i].name;
}
putNamesAsValues('foobar');
```

**Usage:**

The form `name` is the parameter in `putNamesAsValues('foobar');`

Comment: Marked as best answer for the system I am using, both options presented work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementById('form').querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
[].slice.call(inputs).forEach(function(input) {
    var val = input.name.replace(/_/,' ');
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', val);
    input.value = val;
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="FIRST_NAME">
    <input type="text" name="LAST_NAME">
</form>
```

Comment: both options presented work the other option suits the system I am working with more. Thanks for feedback :D